# Fixed effects in probit model

Tags: r

I am kind of desperate at the moment. My teacher says there is a way to add equivalents of industry and year-fixed effects to a probit model. We didn't get any data from him, but we have to explain and give an R template function, how we have to imply those fixed effects in a probit model. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed effect Logit with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87899).

Comment: specifically https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bife/vignettes/howto.html

Comment: Thanks, I can really use the links. I have posted a follow up question below. Hope you can help me.

Comment: It would be good to edit your question to *not* include the "I am kind of desperate at the moment" part.